# Print class inside echo once in foreach and ignore in other loops

Tags: php, foreach

i have foreach like this

EDIT

```
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    echo '<li class="">'. $list .'</li>';
}
```

how i can add active to first li class once like this `class="active"` and other loops show with empy class "default"

> thank you all for helping

Comment: You already got a solution, but here is something extra. Laravel has a `$loop` variable. You can check it: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable`

Comment: thank you, i not use laravel, only use larvel tags to get Interested php poeple to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$active = false;
foreach($lists as $list){
    echo '<li class="'.(!$active ? 'active' : '').'">'. $list .'</li>';
    $active = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$counter = 0;
foeach($lists as $list){
if($counter==0)
 echo '<li class="active">'. $list .'</li>';
else
 echo '<li class="">'. $list .'</li>';
   $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set active to first `<li>` element, then you can do like this.

```
foeach($lists as $key => $list){
       if($key == 0){
           echo '<li class="active">'. $list .'</li>';
       }else{
        echo '<li class="">'. $list .'</li>';
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.3 or higher you can use this

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
<li @if($loop->iteration == 1) class="active" @endif>{{ $list }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to impose some kind of condition on value or index of array. Suppose we have to put active class on first element

```
// track array by its index and first element has index 0
foreach($list as $index => $list)
{
   // if index is 0 then put active class to list with ternary condition
   echo '<li class="'.(($index==0)?'active':'').'">'. $list.'</li>';
}
```